# Git Pull vs Git fetch Which one is Preferable?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I know the difference between `git pull` and `git fetch` .

but i want to know, Which one is Preferable?

because `git pull` doing merge automatically without my knowledge. thats the different i found. `git fetch` wont do that. is there anything else?

Comment: totally different things that are used for totally different actions on your git controlled project....

Comment: They are completely different commands. GIt pull is actually fetch + merge(more or less).

Comment: `git pull` does `git fetch` and `git merge` together

Comment: Which one do you prefer?

Comment: pull will do merge automatically . but there is possibility of generating new commits. in fetch , people might forgot to merge and start to do some task . thats why .. i am confused which one should i  follow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?noredirect=1&lq=1 is the best place where you can find your answer

Comment: Personally I prefer `git fetch`. If you know what `git pull` can do and what it will do, with kinds of options, it's a convenient command. But so far as I've observed, quite some people use it blindly and mess the local repo up, which is quite frustrating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrary to the above comments, `git pull` and `git fetch` are *not* completely different commands.  Rather, doing a `git pull` on a given branch is the same as doing a `git fetch` followed by either merging or rebasing the current branch on its remote counterpart which was just updated.

The utility of doing a `git pull` is that often the reason we fetch is to update a local branch with the version on the remote.  So it is a bit of a convenience.  We can always do fetch followed by merge separately.

Answer (score 8):

`git pull` will do a `git fetch` and then a `git merge`. So it depends what do you want to do.

If you prefer to handle manually the merge you shouldn't use `git pull`

[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: `merge` or `rebase`, according to your configuration.

Comment: i said i know the difference but my question is which one is preferable? pull will do merge without knowledge which is faster than fetch. but there is possibility of generating new commits. in fetch , people might forgot to merge and start to do some task . thats why